# Mostrar fecha solo una vez aunque aparezca repetida

Tags: php

Me gustaría mostrar archivos de la siguiente forma:

```
Fecha de subida
Lista de archivos subidos ese día
Fecha de subida
Lista de archivos subidos ese día
```

Estoy trabajando con `PHP`. Para mostrar los archivos me baso en esta consulta a una base de datos:

```
$sqlfiles = "SELECT * FROM archivos WHERE id_conferencia = '$id'";
```

y este bucle:

```
if( !$result2 = $db->query($sqlfiles) )
{
    echo'Error ejecutando la consulta';
}

echo '<ul>';
    echo '<h2 style="font-size:2.5vmax;" >Archivos disponibles</h2>';
    while( $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc() )
    {           
        echo '<li><a href="archivos/'.$row2['nombre'].'">'. $row2['nombre'] . '</a></li>';
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

Si imprimo la fecha dentro del bucle, el resultado es el siguiente:

```
Fecha
Archivo
Fecha 
Archivo
```

Pero lo que quiero es mostrar la fecha antes de todos los archivos pertenecientes a dicha fecha, independientemente de si esta se repite o no. ¿Habría alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarando una variable en donde se almacene la fecha del registro previo dentro del ciclo justo antes del `while`, con el fin de evaluar si la fecha del actual registro es diferente a la del registro previo, caso tal en el cual si se imprimiría la fecha y se actualizaría el valor de la variable con el del registro actual. Debes tener en cuenta que para el primer registro se debe evaluar si la variable no cuenta con valor alguno.

```
<?php

    $prevDate = NULL;

    while( $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc() ) {

        if ( $prevDate == NULL || $row2['fecha'] != $prevDate ) {
            echo '<li>Fecha ' . $row2['fecha'] . '</li>';
            $prevDate = $row2['fecha'];
        }

        echo '<li><a href="archivos/' . $row2['nombre'] . '">' . $row2['nombre'] . '</a></li>';

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución es ir guardando las fechas en una [tabla hash](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_hash) y solo imprimir la fecha cuando la misma no se encuentre dentro de la tabla. Por ejemplo:

```
$fechas = array();

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {

    if ( !isset($fechas[$row['fecha']]) ) {
        echo '<li>Fecha: ' . $row['fecha'] . '</li>';
        $fechas[$row['fecha']] = 1;
    }

    echo '<li><a href="archivos/' . $row['nombre'] . '">' . $row['nombre'] . '</a></li>';

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ambas respuestas.